# Show Data from Arraylist in list view in Kotlin and Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, listview

In my code Im showing the project name in the list view. But I want to show the name of all added Contacts.

```
showAllContactsBtn.setOnClickListener(){

            val arrayAdapter: ArrayAdapter<Contact> = ArrayAdapter(
                this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listOfAllNames
            )
            listNames.adapter  = arrayAdapter
           listNames.setOnItemClickListener { adapterview, view, x, y ->
                Toast.makeText(this, "Contact picked" + listofAllnames[x].name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
```

How do I show the names like in Toast "list of All names . name"?

Answer (score 1):

An `ArrayAdapter` just calls `toString()` on the items you pass in, and displays those. So you could just pass in all the `name` values instead:

```
val arrayAdapter: ArrayAdapter<Contact> = ArrayAdapter(
    this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listOfAllNames.map { it.name }
)
```

If you need to keep the original objects in the `ArrayAdapter` for whatever reason, you could override the `toString()` method in the objects' class so it just returns the `name`. But since you're just looking up an index in the original data set here, just throwing the list of labels into the `ArrayAdapter` constructor is probably fine!

Comment: Now it want "Contact -> Contact" like listOfAllNames.map{ Contact(it.name,it.surname } ...

Comment: @ProAslan If you're passing in a list of `Contact` objects then you'll have to override the `Contact` class's `toString()` method, i.e. `override fun toString() = name`. If you don't want to do that, and you really do need to pass `Contact` objects into the adapter instead of strings, you'll have to create your own custom adapter - at that point it's probably worth looking into using a `RecyclerView`